# eclipse export war file vs ant buildfile

Tags: java, eclipse, build, ant

I am getting two different outputs from eclipse when exporting my project as a war file and exporting as Ant Buildfile and running that. The main issue here is that eclipse checks for libraries that aren't marked for export (configure build path -> Order and Export) and ignores them, Ant doesn't and includes them in the build.xml.

Is there a way to get the same output or is this the desired behaviour of Ant?